# Parsing JSON Received By Curl Request In C++

Tags: c++, json, libcurl

I've been trying to figure this one out for literally months and I've tried a few different libraries. The problem mostly revolves around the JSON string having special characters (i.e. `{"Token": "123hioh-1o2h90su-1uh2e2", "UserId":12319}`), and not being able to add the necessary slashes or converting it to a raw string. Any help would be much appreciated.

Here is the JSON that the API gives me: `{"Token":"98349dfjd-2038ur23-2839y2023r","TokenId":0,"UserId":280347}`

Comment: Any decent JSON parsing library wouldn't have trouble parsing the example you gave, so what exactly is the trouble you're having?

Comment: @user2740650 It's just the string. The parsers only accept either a raw string or a string that has backslashes inserted, because of the special characters. I can't figure out how to get the string that curl gives me into a form where it can be parsed. I'm also fairly beginner in C++.

Comment: Can you edit the question to show the string that curl gives you?  I assume it's not the JSON in the question because that would be easily parsed by any JSON library.

Comment: Sure, No Problem

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm just not getting your problem.  Take your JSON (either one of those) and paste it into https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/.  It will report that the JSON is valid. Any JSON parsing library will have no trouble parsing it.  Your comment aobut "adding necessary slashes or converting it to a raw string" seems to indicate your problem is NOT about parsing JSON but something else.

Comment: Am I correct in thinking that maybe you already have the JSON, and you **don't** need to parse it, but instead you need to supply it to CURL on the command line for a POST request for example?

Comment: The JSON parsers only take JSON in either a raw string `R"({"Token":"98349dfjd-2038ur23-2839y2023r","TokenId":0,"UserId":280347})"` or with backslashes added to resolve the special characters `{\"project\":\"rapidjson\",\"stars\":10}`. The JSON I receive isn't in either of those forms, and the parsers throw errors.

Comment: I think you'll need to edit your question to show some code that you've tried.